# Impossible (?) NullPointerException - Springframework RabbitMQ, Failed to invoke afterAckCallback

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm running a Java application that uses RabbitMQ Server 3.8.9, spring-amqp-2.2.10.RELEASE, and spring-rabbit-2.2.10.RELEASE.

My test case does something like the following:

1. Start the RabbitMQ Server
2. Start my Java application
3. Test and validate some functionality on my Java application
4. Gracefully stop my Java application
5. Gracefully stop the RabbitMQ Server
6. Repeat 1-6 a few more times

Everything looks fine except sometimes during one of the restarts about 10 minutes into it, I see the following error in my application's logs:

```
2021-02-05 12:52:46.498 UTC,ERROR,org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl,null,rabbitConnectionFactory23,runWorker():1149,Failed to invoke afterAckCallback
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.lambda$doHandleConfirm$1(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:1027) ~[spring-rabbit.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Further analysis doesn't point to anything specific. There are no errors in the RabbitMQ log files, no restarts of the RabbitMQ server, nothing weird in the RabbitMQ logs during the time stamp above.

The code in question:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/v2.2.10.RELEASE/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java#L1027

My tests are automated and run as part of a CI pipeline. The issue is intermittent and I have had trouble reproducing it locally in my sandbox.

From what I can tell, the functionality of my Java application is unaffected.

Code that creates the RabbitMQ connection factory used everywhere:

```
final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOST_NAME);
connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(1);
connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
```

It seems like a concurrency problem, but I'm not so sure on how to get to the bottom of it. For the most part, we use the RabbitTemplate and other Spring facilities to connect to RabbitMQ.

Anyone in the Spring world with some knowledge in RabbitMQ care to chime in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you talk about is like this:

```
finally {
    try {
        if (this.afterAckCallback != null && getPendingConfirmsCount() == 0) {
                this.afterAckCallback.accept(this);
                this.afterAckCallback = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.error("Failed to invoke afterAckCallback", e);
        }
}
```

There is really could be a race condition around that `this.afterAckCallback` property.
We may pass `if()` in one but then different thread makes `this.afterAckCallback` as `null`, so we fail with that NPE.
We have to copy its value to the local variable and then check and perform `accept()`.

Feel free to raise a GitHub issue against Spring AMQP project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues

We have a race condition because we really call this `doHandleConfirm()` with its async logic from the loop in the `processMultipleAck()`.

Comment: Interesting; but we never call the setter with `null`, however, and it is marked `volatile`.

Comment: The `getPendingConfirmsCount()` is `synchronized`, so, the next thread is going to wait for the previous. Therefore when we enter that `if` block, the `this.afterAckCallback` can be `null` already. we probably need to have a double check inside `if`. I don't think it is OK to call `afterAckCallback` the second time when we extract a local variable...

Comment: Oh; sorry, I missed this part `this.afterAckCallback = null;` - doh!

Comment: Here is a possible fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/1304

Comment: Thanks everyone. It looks like I was beat to the punch for filing an issue, but I appreciate the help. 

Edit: I'll accept the answer once the backport is out and validated on our end.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this one! You know you can validate the fix from `SNAPSHOT`. You add `https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot` into your repositories and pull `2.2.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` as dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Artem. I can validate in my sandbox, but our process will not allow SNAPSHOTs.

Comment: One more question. I am seeing this issue show up in our logs more and more, however the functionality of our application does not seem to be affected. Most if not all of our message consumers/producers are set to auto-ack. 

What possible side effects does this NPE have? Is it merely a re-delivery of the same message? Thanks again.

Comment: Not it is not about redelivery and it must really not effect your code. We don't re-throw that exception anyway. And this has nothing to do with consumers. This is only about a delivery confirmation. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#cf-pub-conf-ret